# Refactoring a series of nested try except blocks

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have a class called bit that codes for an svg rectangle.  The class is instantiated with a variable saying what color the svg rectangle should be.  I want it to accept colors in four styles.  hex, rgb percent triplet, rgb integer triplet, and named.  The **init** function then converts the color value to hex.  I've got it working but it relies on a nested try except block and the exceptions thrown by the webcolors module.  If one conversion fails it tries the next, and so on until it either succeeds or raises a final exception.

```
import svgwrite
from webcolors import name_to_hex, normalize_integer_triplet, rgb_percent_to_hex, normalize_hex, normalize_percent_triplet, rgb_to_hex
             
dwg = svgwrite.Drawing('qr.svg')

class Bit:
    def __init__(self, bit_color:str, spec:str='css3'):
        self.bit_type=1
        self.spec=spec
        try:
            self.bit_color=name_to_hex(bit_color,spec)
        except (ValueError, AttributeError):
            try:
                self.bit_color=rgb_to_hex(normalize_integer_triplet(bit_color))
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                try:
                    self.bit_color=rgb_percent_to_hex(normalize_percent_triplet(bit_color))   
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        self.bit_color=normalize_hex(bit_color)
                    except ValueError:
                        raise ValueError('Color not recognized!')
```

While this works and lets the user enter a color in the most common ways, it looks pretty ugly to me.  Is there a way to refactor this?

Comment: Where is the color data coming from? Is it basically right from an end user, or are programmers expected to use this class to handle different formats that come from a standardized source?

Comment: It seems that the "usual" way to refactor this is to check the input value to determine what you have, rather than throwing the data at various functions to see which one does *not* throw and exception.

Comment: I've written a color class in JS once. My approach was to use regex to determine the input format (HEX, RGB, HSV, HSL, CMYK, NCOL, [WebColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value), ...) and then use the appropriate conversion.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The color data (i.e. the color string) will come from the user.  I thought about using regex to determine the input but since the webcolors library already has functions that will throw exceptions if the data is bad I thought I'd use them instead of using regex and writing my own exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
        try:
            self.bit_color=name_to_hex(bit_color, spec)
            return
        except (ValueError, AttributeError):
            pass
            
        try:
            self.bit_color=rgb_to_hex(normalize_integer_triplet(bit_color))
            return
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass

        try:
            self.bit_color=rgb_percent_to_hex(normalize_percent_triplet(bit_color))   
            return
        except ValueError:
            pass

        try:
            self.bit_color=normalize_hex(bit_color)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('Color not recognized!')
```

Comment: What effect do return statements have in a class init function?

Comment: Same as in any function, they cause execution of the function to stop.  I'm assuming that setting the `bit_color` is the only thing this function does -- if it's not, I'd push this logic into a helper function.

Comment: Right now that's all it does.  I would like to leave open the option of adding more things to the init function.  I guess I could put them before this step

Comment: @Samwise sorry misread the the final part of the question! I deleted my answer